# sort arraylist using startwith for api < 24

Tags: java, android, java-stream, comparator

I created an autocompleteTextView that shows the results that I got from a client depanding of the query the user entered.

The results from the client arent ordered in any way.

For example, if the users typed harry pot I could get:

```
harry and the tree
the trees and harry
harry pot right
ben and harry
harry and be
```

and so on.

I would like that the results will appear by relevance = if the user typed in harry pot I want to assume that it starts with harry pot.

```
harry pot right
harry and be
harry and the tree
the trees and harry
ben and harry
```

How could I sort my ArrayList to show first the results start with this query?

I tried to use `stream` or `comperator` but both require API >= 24.

Any way to do it for lower API? (specifically needs API = 21).

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

To sort a `List` call [`Collections.sort(list, comparator)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections#sort(java.util.List%3CT%3E,%20java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20T%3E)) *(API level 1)*.

Comment: I cant find anything with regard to comparator and startsWith and how to implement it.

Comment: @Ben Since none of the results start with `"harry pot"`, there is nothing to sort.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
Collections.sort(arrayList, new Comparator<Element>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Element element, Element t1) {
        if(element.time > t1.time) return -1;
        else return 1;
    }
});
```

It work for API 23

Comment: You might be able to shorten that with a lambda (`(element, t1) -> t1.time - element.time` or something like that). Not sure where you're getting `Element` and time from, though, the question doesn't seem to include that.